# Can I switch back to the previous object treeview in PowerApps Application Creator

Tags: powerapps

I'm pursuing Microsoft PL-100 Course. I need to create model-driven app, but my object treeview differs from what I can see in course tutorial - screenshots below.

[What I can see in PowerApps Application Creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyRT8.png)

[What it should look like according to course walkthrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baLOi.png)

The problem is that it's not only visuals that are different, the object model is not the same. I.e. There are no subgroups. Weirdest fact is that some of my colegues have the correct treeview without changing any settings and we work at the same environment.

I've search through all settings with no success. Also I tried creating objects I need through site map but when I go back to the app, it's still looking different (even worse).

Maybe there is a way to switch between those two?